# Confused about rails active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

4 model has following columns in their table

```
student : student_id  name    dept
semester: semester_id semester_name
subject : subject_id  subject_name  semester_id
result  : student_id  semester_id   result_id result
```

I have associated the models as

```
student: has_many semesters
         has_many subjects through semesters
         has_many results through semesters

semester: belongs_to students
          has_many subjects
          has_many results

subject: belongs_to semesters
         has_many student through semesters

result: has_many students through semesters
        belongs_to semesters
```

Let me know if this is okay. I am confused about when to use belongs_to. I mean, can I use something like below?

```
student: has_many semesters
         has_many subjects through semesters            

semester: has_many students
          has_many subjects              

subject: has_many semesters
         has_many student through semesters
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is this:

```
Student: has_many :semesters
         has_many :subjects, through: semesters            

Semester: belongs_to :student
          belongs_to :subject              

Subject: has_many :semesters
         has_many :students, through: :semesters
```

You need the following migrations:

```
drop_table :results # you won't need it anymore if you use has_many through
remove_column :students, :student_id, :integer
add_column :students, :id, :integer # if you don't have the ID column in your students table
remove_column :subjects, :subject_id, :integer
add_column :subjects, :id, :integer
add_reference :semesters, :student, index: true
add_reference :semesters, :subject, index: true
```

Comment: I have updated the table columns. Please check now and let me know how can I do the association

Answer (score 0):

The class has belongs_to definition is always the correspond db tables with the foreign key declaration.

Comment: I have updated the table columns. Please check now and let me know how can I do the association

Comment: @user1478137 you table columns seems a lot of problems. Let us clarify what you wanna to do. I think we should start from semester. 1. The system has many semesters. 2. For each semester there are lots of subjects. 3. For each subject there will be many students. 4. For each student it will has a result for each subject he go to. Are these right?